# Cannot write date in BigQuery using Java Bigquery Client API

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm doing some ETL from a CSV file in GCS to BQ, everything works fine, except for dates. The field name in my table is TEST_TIME and the type is DATE, so in the TableRow I tried passing a java.util.Date, a com.google.api.client.util.DateTime, a String, a Long value with the number of seconds, but none worked.

I got error messages like these:
Could not convert non-string JSON value to DATE type. Field: TEST_TIME; Value: ...

When using DateTime I got this error:
JSON object specified for non-record field: TEST_TIME.

```
//tableRow.set("TEST_TIME", date);
//tableRow.set("TEST_TIME", new DateTime(date));
//tableRow.set("TEST_TIME", date.getTime()/1000);
//tableRow.set("TEST_TIME", dateFormatter.format(date)); //e.g. 05/06/2016
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you're expected to pass a `String` in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, which is similar to if you were using the REST API directly with JSON. Try this:

```
tableRow.set("TEST_TIME", "2017-04-06");
```

If that works, then you can convert the actual date that you have to that format and it should also work.

Comment: it worked... I was under the wrong impression that the API would know how to handle dates! Kinda disappointing.

Answer (score 5):

While working with google cloud dataflow, I used a wrapper from Google for timestamp - `com.google.api.client.util.DateTime`.

This worked for me while inserting rows into Big Query tables. So, instead of

```
tableRow.set("TEST_TIME" , "2017-04-07");
```

I would recommend

```
tableRow.set("TEST_TIME" , new DateTime(new Date()));
```

I find this to be a lot cleaner than passing timestamp as a string.

Comment: I did that, but I guess it works only from the TIMESTAMP type, not for DATE type.

Comment: @CCC you are right, for timestamp unix seconds as integer (1514800800) works and string literal also works ("2018-01-02 00:00:00"), for date only string literal ("2018-01-02") works

Answer (score 1):

Using the Java class com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow, to set milliseconds since UTC into a BigQuery TIMESTAMP do this:

```
tableRow.set("timestamp", millisecondsSinceUTC / 1000.0d);
```

tableRow.set() expects a floating point number representing **seconds** since UTC with up to microsecond precision.

Very non-standard and undocumented (set() boxes the value in an object, so it's unclear what data types set() accepts. The other proposed solution of using com.google.api.client.util.DateTime did not work for me.)